# Regex: Capture only 1 instance of a match

Tags: regex

Lets say I have a capture group that grabs a list of non-unique results. For example:

```
100
120
100
140
150
150
```

The repeated matches are not necessarily adjacent, as in the case of `100`.  I want to modify my regex in order to get only the first instance of a match. For the example above, my expected output would be:

```
100
120
140
150
```

My specific case refers to the (sanitized) regex `(blah-\d{5}-)`. How could I modify my regex to grab only the first instances of a match out of my list of matches?

Comment: You should capture these values and then run something like `.unique()` on the list. What is the programming language? Also, what does `(blah-\d{5}-)` have to do with the number list? Please describe the real life problem, you might have oversimplified it.

Comment: I would definitely go with @WiktorStribiżew's suggestion, but an easy way to do this in regex is to flip your contents and use [`^(\d+)$\v(?=(?:[\s\S]*^\1$)+)`](https://regex101.com/r/6A8BNM/2) then flip the contents back.